# NInject: Bind Multiple Services to Single Interface

Tags: c#, ninject

I have interface IFoo with 2 implementations Foo1 and Foo2.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Process();
}

public class Foo1 : IFoo 
{
    public void Process()
    {
    }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public void Process()
    {
    }
}
```

I'm registering them as shown below.

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
                .FromAssemblyContaining<IFoo>()
                .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IFoo>()
                .BindAllInterfaces()
                .Configure(b => b.InRequestScope()));
```

I'm trying to get all IFoo services like this

```
public class TestController: ApiController
{
    public TestController(IFoo[] fooServices)
    {

    }
}
```

But services list fooServices is empty. I want to get all my 2 services instead.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried to manually bind multiple types to the same interface instead of your Linq expression? Just to make sure if it is a binding error or resolution error.

Comment: @spender, thank you for commenting. I'll try this out.

Comment: @ckury, you have a hint! That worth trying either

Comment: ...sorry, deleted my last comment because I wasn't sure it was current. After looking through ninject source, looks fine. You can inspect all the bindings in a kernel with the code at the top of this github issue. Take a peek to see if you've actually bound anything... https://github.com/ninject/ninject/issues/104

Comment: @spender, thanks for sharing method for getting all keys. It is really helpful.

Comment: @ckury, it was problem with linq ninjutsu, direct registering works fine.

Comment: i cant vote for comments, so @spender paste your code with reflection to get all keys as answer, i will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

The problem was the fact, that plugin libraries are loaded via custom assembly resolver AFTER registering of services. So we exposed Kernel as static property and performed registering of its services after it was loaded.

Next issue was that 'binding' could not register 2 plugins with 1 interface.
It was resolved by traversing through each plugin types and getting their interfaces and registering as follows:

```
foreach (var interfaceType in pluginServiceType.GetInterfaces())
   kernel.bind(interfaceType).to(pluginServiceType)
```

Comment: Glad you got there... Didn't post my comment as it isn't a direct answer, just a diagnostic tool to help you get there.